# Add image on top of TableView

Tags: uitableview, uiimageview, uiimage

This probably a dumb question but i've really been struggling with it for a minute now. I created a UITableView programmatically got all the data flowing perfectly, now i just want to add a static image on top of the table and can't seem to be able  to do it:-( I know this is probably very basic but i really need somebody to help me out with it.

Answer (score 4):

Well i ended up doing it in code and here it is.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ranking_bar.png"];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,320,30);

    return imageView;

}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 30;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so normally u would create a UITableViewController that will delegate how the table works (this is where numberOfSectionsInTableView, numberOfSectionsInTableView, etc.) methods are.  to make the cells themselves different then default u need to create a subclass of UITableViewCell

customcell.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface CustomCell : UITableViewCell {

    UILabel *primaryLabel;
    UIImageView *myImageView;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *primaryLabel;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *myImageView;
@end
```

customcell.m

```
#import "CustomCell.h"


@implementation CustomCell
@synthesize primaryLabel,myImageView;
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {

    if (self = [super initWithFrame:frame reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier]) {

        // Initialization code

        primaryLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];

        primaryLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;

        primaryLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:20];

        primaryLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

        primaryLabel.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

        myImageView = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

        [self.contentView addSubview:primaryLabel];

        [self.contentView addSubview:myImageView];

    }

    return self;

}

- (void)layoutSubviews {

    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;

    CGFloat boundsX = contentRect.origin.x;

    CGRect frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+10 ,0, 300, 40);

    myImageView.frame = frame;

    frame= CGRectMake(boundsX+70 ,5, 200, 25);

    primaryLabel.frame = frame;


}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)dealloc
{
    [myImageView release];
    [primaryLabel release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
}
```

then back to your UITableViewController : cellforrowatindexpath method u should allocate ur custom cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    CustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[CustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    }

    // Configure the cell...
    NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
    NSString *pathString= [snowBoardArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *string2= @"Cell";
    pathString = [pathString stringByAppendingString:string2];



    cell.primaryLabel.text=[snowBoardArray objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:pathString ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *theImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    cell.myImageView.image = theImage;
    [theImage release];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your reply, actually i don't even want the image inside the tabs, my table starts at Y30px so i have an empty space on top and this is where i want to put a static image.

Comment: I guess another way to put would be how can i add an image at the coordinates (0,0,320,30)?

Comment: have u tried just using interface builder?  i know for one of my apps i did this, all i did was put a UIPictureView (from memory dont remember the exact name of a picture view) above the table and resize it to fit then select your image.  i think im missing something though because you sound well versed and this is a very simple approach

Comment: Actualy i usually create my tables with IB this time i'm using a different approach and just need a simple UIImageView on my view, i know it can sound crazy but i just can't get it to work for some reason maybe a good night sleep with do the trick for me:-)

Comment: maybe!  good luck!  id ask u to post ur code but i dont even think that would help, especially with the IB stuff

Comment: Well if you wanna take a look here's what i have

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30)];
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ranking_bar.png"];
    [self.view addSubView:imageView];

Comment: yea i actually ended up putting it on the header. Thanks for your help!

Comment: glad to hear.  did u use IB or do it in code?  if u did it in code u should post it and mark it as the answer.

Comment: i did it with code and here it is:- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 
 UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"ranking_bar.png"];
 UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:myImage] autorelease];
 imageView.frame = CGRectMake(10,10,320,30);
 
 return imageView;
    
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
 return 30;
}

Answer (score 0):

```
    -(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{  

    UIImageView *imageView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"urImg.png"]] autorelease];  
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(5,5,320,30);
    return imageView;
}

(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section   
  {   
      return 30;  
 }
```

Comment: copy and pasted from actual answer